# How to Close one jframe inside the other jframe in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have one main `JFrame` and one secondary `JFrame`. Now i want to close one `JFrame` but when I close that `JFrame` the main `JFrame` also gets closed. But I don't want that to get closed, so how do I stop it in java?

Comment: Relevant: [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) -TL;DR: It is bad practice and not user friendly. So instead of two `JFrame`s, depending on your use-case 1) use a modal `JDialog` to display intermediate information, or 2) use a `CardLayout` to switch between context in your `JFrame`.

Comment: You probably should show your `close` methods. Maybe you have somewhere a `System.exit(..)`?

Comment: Pssst.. the secret lies in the default close operation used for the frames in the code not shown. But follow the advice of @maloomeister, since there never should *be* two frames.

Answer (score 0):

there's a function in `JFrame` called `setDefaultCloseOperation(...)`

You can do:

`setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)` which will set the visibility of the secondary frame to `false` instead of exiting the program